# Sum of row values in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new to Google Sreadsheets syntax, so forgive me if this sounds too trivial. :)

I want to sum up the row values of certain columns in my Google Spreadsheets sheet into a new column.

I'm looking for the right command to do this.

**Minimal Working Example**

```
     | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Sum B + D |
     |----------|----------|----------|----------|-----------|
Row 1| a1       | b1       | c1       | d1       | b1 + d1   |
Row 2| a2       | b2       | c2       | d2       | b2 + d2   |
Row 3| a3       | b3       | c3       | d3       | b3 + d3   |
```

I want to construct the last column (Sum B + D) with a spreadsheet formula.

Comment: I've looked at that supposed duplicate and I found it unsatisfactory. Moreover my question is much more comprehensive and clear, not to mention my MWE.

Comment: What language settings are you using in Excel?

Comment: English, I guess. I'm using Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: The syntax is different in Excel and Google Spreadsheets. Please update your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cell E1 add one of the following formulas

```
=B1 + D1
```

or

```
=ADD(B1,D1)
```

or

```
=SUM(B1,D1)
```

Note: The argument separator could be ; (semicolon) instead of , (comma). It depends on the regional setting being used.

Then fill down as necessary.

If you want to avoid to have to do fill down then use the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(B1:B3 + D1:D3)
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the following if you wnat to sum *every* row in columns A, D and E

```
=SUM(A:A,D:D,E:E)
```

or this if you just want to sum, say, the first 15 rows

```
=SUM(A1:A15,D1:D15,E1:E15)
```

Basically SUM can take more than one range parameter!

It may not be what you need right now but SUMIFS are also very useful. This allows you to sum one range based on one or more conditions in other ranges.

Comment: I get a parse error when using `=SUM(A:A,D:D,E:E)`. Does the previous command match the intent of my given example?

Comment: The second formula is more in line with your intention. You can try with your exact range by typing =SUM( and then highlighting each of the ranges you want to include. (To select them all, keep the Ctrl key pressed down, while selecting your ranges with the mouse and left click.)

Comment: The formulas provided will sum all the cells but the OP mentioned that he want to sum certain cells in the same rows.